# Can't make vimwiki honor setting passed via command line

Tags: linux, plugin-vimwiki

I am trying to write a wrapper shell script that is supposed to launch vim with a vimwiki in current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

gvim -c "let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '$PWD/'}] | normal ,ww"
```

The `normal` command works (the comma is my custom remapped `<Leader>`), but it doesn't honor the custom `path` option.

To reproduce the problem, just run the above script somewhere not in home directory. At startup, vim will ask to create `~/vimwiki` instead of using current working directory. Yet after I skip that question and do

```
:echo g:vimwiki_list
```

in vim's command line, it displays the correct current directory. So it's not a problem of the correct value of **$PWD** getting passed to vim, I use the bash variable inside double quotes so this part is fine.

How to debug and eventually fix it?

I had a customized g:vimwiki_list in my vimrc, but I also tried with defaults by commenting that part, the problem still persists (Is it true that settings passed via command line the way I did aren't overwritten by the ones hardcoded in vimrc anyway?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands given with `-c` are executed after the first file is loaded. I guess that at that time, vimwiki is already initialized and asked for creation of the directory `~/vimwiki`.

Use `--cmd ...`. This commands are executed *before* `vimrc` is loaded. So the variable should be set at the time vimwiki is initializing.

Untested:

```
gvim --cmd "let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '$PWD/'}]" -c "normal ,ww"
```

So `g:vimwiki_list` is assigned before `vimrc` is sourced and `,ww` is executed after the first file was loaded.

See `:help --cmd` and `:help -c`.